# How to initialize CommandLine class?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am working with [this command Line class](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/os/CommandLine.html) of **org.openqa.selenium.os** package and wanted to execute a dir command get the output to my java code.

here is, what i have just tried,

```
String[] cmds={"date","dir"};
CommandLine cl=new CommandLine(cmds);
cl.execute();
System.out.println("The out put is "+cl.getStdOut());
```

i get this,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Unable to find executable for: date
at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:236)
at org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess.<init>(UnixProcess.java:61)
at org.openqa.selenium.os.CommandLine.<init>(CommandLine.java:47)
```

What i did wrong ? i jsut googled but no luck. you can also check [this](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-remote-driver/2.0b2/org/openqa/selenium/os/CommandLine.java) to know what CommandLine class does.

I am using Windows XP 32 bit and getting the same exception for all the commands.

Comment: `cls` is a builtin command of the command interpreter; it is not a "real" command. This is why Selenium cannot find the executable since it doesn't execute processes with a command interpreter

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In computing, CLS (for clear screen) is a command used by the command line interpreters COMMAND.COM and CMD.EXE on DOS, OS/2 and Microsoft Windows operating systems to clear the screen or console window of commands and any output generated by them.

see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CLS_(command)

if you run `cmd -c cls` you will get your desired result

Comment: same reason.  If you ran java.exe or another .exe is should work